# Net pay = Gross pay issues

Tags: c#

I have a very simple program to calculate gross and net pay based on input by the user, I'm getting the same figure for net and gross pay. Can someone tell me why taxes aren't being taken into account based on this? I omitted some code so it should be small enough for someone to read quickly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter tax percentage: 23 for divorced, 13 for                                                              widowed, 15 for married, 22 for single");
            taxPercentage = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double statusTax = taxPercentage / 100;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of overtime hours earned");
            overtimeHours = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            overtimeRate = 1.5;
            double overtimePay = overtimeHours * overtimeRate;
            double grossPay = overtimePay + normalPay;
            double netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * statusTax);
            Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay is");
            Console.WriteLine(grossPay);
            Console.WriteLine("Net pay is");
            Console.WriteLine(netPay);                                       
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect your `taxPercentage` is less than `100` so your `statusTax` will be `0` because of [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) performing *even* if you wanna save it as a `double`.

That's why your

```
double netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * statusTax);
```

will be

```
double netPay = grossPay - (grossPay * 0);
```

and

```
double netPay = grossPay;
```

To solve this, change one of your operands to floating-point value like;

```
double statusTax = taxPercentage / 100.0;
```

or

```
double statusTax = (double)taxPercentage / 100;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That fixed the problem entirely. You are a godsend.